# Object #<Object> has no method 'indexOf' Use --force to continue

Tags: gruntjs, jscs

```
jscs: {
        src: ['<%= config.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'],
        options: {
           config: '.jscsrc'
        },
        force: true

    },
```

This is my Grunt file config
I am trying to use plugin described https://github.com/jscs-dev/grunt-jscs/

After loading the task it throws me an error

```
Running "jscs:files" (jscs) task
Warning: Object #<Object> has no method 'indexOf' Use --force to continue.
```

Resetting  `force:true`  allows me to continue, but i want the task to fail if anyone in the team avoids this.
How can i fix this ?

Comment: Hello @Sukhmeet. I'm one of the maintainers of that plugin. I'm afraid that's an issue of [multi-task configuration](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#task-configuration-and-targets). Those examples you posted, are the real ones? If so, could you post the plugin version you're using?

Comment: Hey @gustavohenke , i am using version 1.12.0
You can find my full grunt file  at https://www.dropbox.com/s/p4nthid1amumrvq/Gruntfile.js?dl=0